# How to assign foreign key related field while creating model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have model League one of its field **country_code** relate as foreign key to another model Country

```
class League(models.Model):                           
    league = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)                                                   
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)                                                   
    country_code = models.ForeignKey("Country",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)                 

class Country(models.Model):                          
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)
    flag = models.URLField(null=True)               
    lastModified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When i am trying to create League object

```
data_json = leagues_json["api"]["leagues"]      
for item in data_json:                                 
    league_id = item["league_id"]                   
    league_name = item["name"]                      
    country = item["country"]                                              
    b = League.objects.create(league = league_id,league_name = league_name,country_code = country)
```

I get en error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'World'": "League.country_code" must be a "Country" instance.
```

Like i understand error occurs because while i am creating object i didn't assign to `country_code` field proper `Country` object.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get the `Country` object first and then using it to create the `League`.

Maybe like this (assuming that `item["country"]` holds the country code):

```
for item in data_json:                                 
    country = Country.objects.get(code=item["country"])
    b = League.objects.create(
        league=item["league_id"],
        league_name=item["name"],
        country_code=country)
```

Note that this code:

- will do a database lookup in each loop; this could potentially be optimised to reduce queries.
- raises an error if the country does not exist; you can add a try-except block to handle those cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot. unfortunately i didn't have rights to flag your answer like correct((